# Reputation and trust should be separated

Tags: feature-request

In StackoverFlow and sister sites 'reputation' serve a dual purpose - person's hold on the subject matter and trust that he won't spam or vandalize.

**IMHO** 'trust score' need to be separated out of reputation score, and this ***'trust score' should be carried over to all stack sites***.

***So, reputation affects how much you are trusted by fellow stackers and 'trust score' affects how much you are trusted by the site system.***

A possible use case would be:-

Suppose I have a high reputation in StackOverflow.com but not in Serverfault.com, since it is not part of my active interests. I google and find an answer on Serverfault.com which I find to be good and want to Vote Up, but can't as my reputation is low.

Here comes the trust part. A member who understands the answer and finds it useful would only want to Vote Up, except for vandals. So in this case 'trust score' should be used.

Hope all these makes sense.

Comment: Your example is not effective, since you can associate accounts and get 100 bonus to do upvote.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that!

Comment: It doesn't make any sense, how does a "site system" know more than the SO users?  It is just a chunk of silicon, it won't become self-aware for another decade or two.

Comment: Well based on 'trust score' ofcourse. Anyway since 100 reputations are carried over so I guess you can consider this question **Closed**.

Comment: This is only a problem on Stack Overflow anyway, because there you can gain rep far more easily than on some other sites like Super User or Ask Ubuntu. The fact that even I as a mod am not trusted on some sites does sting a little ;P